# Photoshop artboard blending mode conflict

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, blending

Whenever I try to blend an image to an artboard - i get the conflict shown below on artboard 3. However I started a new document with a transparent background  and it blended properly as shown on artboard 1 ...added new artboards and the blending problem returned. How do I make artboards blend friendly ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me, are you sure what you mean is 'blending'? Is Artboard 1 the result you are trying to get? Because that looks more like a clipping mask to me.

Comment: Yes artboard,  1 is the result I'm trying to get. What do you mean by clip masking ?

Comment: can you explain to us how exactly you achieved artboard 1 in the first place? Infomation about clipping masks can be found here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/clipping-masks.html

Comment: i started the document as something that is not an artboard, then added artboards using artboard tool....then on the artboard that was not an artboard before , the images blend correctly , but on the new artboards - the result is the aforementioned problem. For some reason , I can't pull it off as I did before.

Comment: no I'm asking what you do to 'blend' the images.

Comment: Oh, I take an image , (the black background with light element in it), put it above the text layer ( as indicated above) ...Then apply blending mode  "screen".

Answer (score 1):

So this is only half an answer, but hopefully something that will help you.

The 'better' way to put an image over something like text or shape is using a **clipping mask**. This method is generally better because it leaves clean edges around the text or object whereas using a blend mode can affect objects/text around the blended object as well.

To use a clipping mask:

- make sure the layer you want to blend over text/object is on top of the text/object.
- Right click on the top layer and select 'Create clipping mask'

Your layers will now look like this:
[image]

When using this method I do not have the problem you describe in your post so hopefully it will also accidentally solve your problem.